# I am not able to select text pdfiumViewer

Tags: c#, pdfium

I am not able to select text pdfiumViewer after convert  from base64 to stream  and give it to the PdfIumViewer, Is there any way to enable textSelection.

```
PdfiumViewer.PdfViewer pdf;

string base64ImageRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(byteFile[a]);
var stream = new MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64ImageRepresentation));
PdfDocument pdfDocum = PdfDocument.Load(stream);
pdf.Document = pdfDocum;
```

Comment: When you say "stram", do you probably rather mean "stream"?

Comment: @StefanWuebbe yes i mean  Stream but i forget the e

Comment: @KJ in fact if i save the file .pdf it work normal but when i convert it to byte then base64 then stream i lose the permession to select the test in this file but i don't know when i lose this

Comment: thank you @KJ it was a pleasure talking to you